# manipulating regexp matching for dialcodes

Tags: regex, tcl

I have to make a switch in Tcl that returns the adequate message for each dial code entered. The dial codes looks like:

```
*20*
**20
*20*0
* 20 *1
* 20 *[number_made_of_3_digits]
```

The problem is that I'm new in tcl and in regexp usage, so I tried the below, but I couldn't make it work:

Attempt:

```
set sttring "*20*612"
set b [regexp { (\*20\*) } $sttring a]
puts "b= $b" 
puts "a= $a"
```

Another attempt:

```
set sttring "*20*612"
set b [regexp { *20*(6[0-9][0-9]) } $sttring a]
puts "b= $b" 
puts "a= $a"
```

but nothing happens.

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Since braces are quoting mechanisms, spaces inside are significant: `{ (\*20\*) }` is space, star, 2, 0, star, space.

Comment: Could you please put the desired result with each of the different dial code you have? The question as is, is not clear I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [sample program](http://goo.gl/sPbmzo) for you to check:

```
set sttring "*20*612"
set rest [regexp {\*(\d{2})\*(\d{3})} $sttring match match2 match3]
puts $rest
puts $match
puts $match2
puts $match3
```

Output:

```
1        - We got a match                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
*20*612  - The whole match (Group 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
20       - Captured Group 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
612      - Captured Group 2 (2nd parentheses)
```

I hope this can help you with your further investigations.